# Use C functions in Idris

Tags: c, idris

Idris can compile .idr  to C-code (JS, NodeJS). Is it possible to do so in reverse direction - compile C-code to Idris format? Or, maybe, to use C functions direct in Idris code?

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Take a look at the [foreign function interface (FFI)](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/ffi.html). Based on your compilation target (f.e. C, JavaScript, …) you can use the native functions like this example call of `void *fileOpen(char *path, char *mode)` inside the `IO` monad:

```
do_fopen : String -> String -> IO Ptr
do_fopen f m
   = foreign FFI_C "fileOpen" (String -> String -> IO Ptr) f m
```